# CodeBuild::Project cloud formation not able to add artifact primary, artifcat1, artifcat2 and so on

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiOcK.png): [image: Screen from codebuild Artifacts]

according to this document it only talks about a single object "Artifacts" which creates the primary, but doesn't take more than one object in a list format to add "Artifact2" or "Artifcat3" or so on.. does anybody have any idea?

currently, this is what i have and it creates the primary only.

```
  Artifacts:
    ArtifactIdentifier: ''
    EncryptionDisabled: true
    Location: !Sub ${Environment}-ithor-ss-artifacts
    OverrideArtifactName: true
    Name: ss-ui-dev.zip
    NamespaceType: NONE
    Packaging: ZIP
    Path: ss/WebUI/
    Type: S3
```